# UDP packets lost when using windows but not Linux

Tags: linux, windows, udp

I am trying to work out what could be causing a strange issue I have been observing when testing a system.

The system under test recieves HTTP requests via UDP from an external source. For testing I have mocked out this source using Python sending the UDP packets over a local network for testing I send 1, 20, 133 and 1000 messages.

When I run the test on my local windows machine I regularily get a drop out of UDP packets with sometimes even the single message failing to be recieved. however when I create a virtual Linux Box (Centos) using Virtual Box and run the same tests from there I get 100% success rate 100% of the time.

Are there any know issues with sending UDP messages from Windows, any strange buffering differences between Windows and Linux I could adjust for on my machine?

Comment: UDP is not a reliable protocol, and applications that use it should be prepared for packet loss. High volume can overflow buffers and then packets will be discarded.

Comment: What are you using to receive the packets on Windows and Linux?

Comment: @Barmar OP seems to be aware of that. The question is about the difference in loss between Windows and Linux.

Comment: Probably just a difference in the number of buffers it makes available for UDP. There might be a registry setting to tune it.

Comment: @Barmar the decision for UDP has been forced on us by a client, however I would expect consitant failiures between using Linux and Windows, not the massive discrepancy between the 2. In adition packet loss over a LAN shyould be minimal to 0.

Comment: I don't see why you would expect consistency between Linux and Windows, they're totally different designs. What is the rate that you're sending when you lose packets?

Comment: @Malt we are using a bespoke system writtten in C++ to recieve the packets

Comment: Windows I send 1, 20, 133 and 1000 over 4 tests, about 30% of the time the 1 message fails, roughly 50% of the time the 20 1-3 messages lost, the 133 approx 70% between 1-15 messages lost and 1000 approx 90% between 1-32 messages messages lost. On Linux 100% sucess 100% of the time. Figured it might be buffering in Windows that Linux des differently or not at all.

Answer (score 1):

UDP stacks of operating systems usually drops a received UDP packet, if the incoming packet does not fit to receive buffer. The receive buffer may be 'full', if the receiving application does not read it (=socket) fast enough.

Default size of receive buffer of your Windows may be smaller than in the Linux.

For handling bursts of incoming UDP packets better, you could increase size of the receiving buffer:

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 65536)
```

You can also use `getsockopt` for checking the size.

Comment: The recieving size has a more then big enough buffer set up and does not change between testing Windows and Linux. We have isolated the issue to being on the Sending side of the system on Windows.

Comment: Ok, There is SO_SNDBUF option for the sending side. I am not sure how it works with UDP.

Answer (score 0):

having researched and investigated it seems that despite my efforts to try and prove otherwise the answer is, it's just Windows. Windows Network Buffering is causing the problem. As fixing this is outside the remit of this question i will close this and if necessary open a new question, thanks for your help.